# Opera/Safari displays my custom font (Fontface) in an unusual pixelated manner.

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

My site looks perfectly identical on IE, Chrome and Firefox but it is having issues with Safari and Opera. Now the issue specificaly in opera is that all fonts are pixelated and really horrible. In Safari the issue is nearly the same but it seems that bigger text works and smaller text nearly unreadable.

I use the Html5 doctype and:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

It is hard to explain but here is the fontface code I have made:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'modern';
    src:url('../fonts/modern.eot');
    src:url('../fonts/modern.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/modern.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/modern.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/modern.svg#modern') format('svg');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;

}
```

Now here is the "Menu" text css which displays really bad in opera and firefox:

```
height:80px;
width:200px;
border-radius:45px 45px 0 0;
-moz-border-radius:50px;
-webkit-border-radius:50px 50px 50px 50px;
-o-border-radius:50px 50px 50px 50px;
border-top:2px solid #000;
transition:all 1s;
moz-transition:all 1s;
-webkit-transition:all 1s;
-o-transition:all 1s;
color:#a0a0a0;
display:block;
font-family:modern;
font-size:23px;
font-weight:700;
letter-spacing:1px;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
line-height:70px;
background:url(../images/menu_plate.png) no-repeat;
opacity:0.7;
}
```

And here another part. This one displays fairly normal in Safari but not in chrome.

```
h2,h3 {
border-bottom:1px dashed #d2d2d2;
color:#b4b4b4;
font-family:modern;
font-size:50px;
font-weight:400;
line-height:1.2em;
margin-bottom:15px;
text-align:left;
padding:25px 0 5px;
}
```

Now I tried changing the font-face font weight to 400 or 700. Nothing works. Tried removing the font weight value of the classes. Nothing. Actually as you can see my code is pretty much valid but I just cant figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `-webkit-font-smoothing`. Also, try running your fonts through Font Squirrel.

If you're on a Mac, you can also try disabling font-smoothing altogether (System Preferences > General > Use LCD font smoothing when available [uncheck]). Be sure to restart your browser after changing this setting for it to apply. If this turns out to be the issue, I'd try re-generating the font files with something like Font Squirrel. It has helped my fonts a lot compared to a desktop font conversion tool I have. I have submitted this bug to Apple, and they responded saying it's "intended behavior", which blew my mind.

Comment: Looks like he used FontSquirrel. You can tell from the `#iefix`

Comment: I've used other tools that apply the same thing.